# White space between caption and sidewaystable

Tags: tables, positioning, captions, rotating

I am using a sidewaystable from the `rotating` package.
I am trying to add some white space between the caption and the table (caption is placed above table). I tried using `\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}` in the preamble as well as `\captionsetup{skip=10pt}` directly before the `\caption`in the sidewaystable environment. Neither works. The first option affects all regular tables but not the sidewaystable, the latter does not have any effect.

Suggestions how I can do this? And it is important, that it is only for this table and does not affect the other table captions.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}` works fine here, can you add a complete, yet minimal example showing the problem?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you! The thing is, I dont want the skip for the regular tables, only for the one sidewaystable Im using...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think I misunderstood you a little, I see the problem now. I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: If it's only going to apply for a single, sideways-set table, could you just insert `\medskip`, `\bigskip`, or `\vspace*{10pt}` after `\caption` and before `\begin{tabular}`?

Comment: @Mico: I have not tried your solution yet, but the suggested method by Torbjorn works perfectly. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why `\captionsetup` doesn't have any effect inside a `sidewaystable`, what you can do instead is to place the `\captionsetup` just before the `sidewaystable`, and surround both in a pair of braces (`{ .. }`). The brace pair localises the caption setting.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Word}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

{\captionsetup[table]{aboveskip=2cm}\begin{sidewaystable} % opening brace on beginning of line
\centering
\caption{Word}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}} % <- closing brace

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Word}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! This works just, thanks a lot! :) Actually, I needed to use `belowskip`not `aboveskip`, but then that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks